# Force spline to pass through (1, 1) in mgcv

Tags: r, splines, mgcv

In running GAM models on my simulated data, I'm wondering if I actually need to contain splines to pass through a specific point (in my case (1, 1)).

From my understanding the default in mgcv is for splines to pass through the origin (0, 0). Perhaps this could explain why my GAMs have been so badly behaved when it comes to autocorrelation in deviance residual plots via gam.check()? I am familiar with mgcv, but by no means an expert. Please correct me if my thinking is flawed.

I did find a solution provided by Simon Wood on NabbleR, but it is multiple steps. Is there a cleaner way to accomplish this?

EDIT:

Here is the data with output.

```
       x    y
1      1 1.0000
2      2 1.8024
3      3 2.4385
4      4 2.9585
5      5 3.3706
6      6 3.6891
7      7 3.9497
8      8 4.1624
9      9 4.3137
10    10 4.4670
11    11 4.5581
12    12 4.6408
13    13 4.7139
14    14 4.7722
15    15 4.8197
16    16 4.8503
17    17 4.8852
18    18 4.9042
19    19 4.9224
20    20 4.9396
21    21 4.9482
22    22 4.9616
23    23 4.9673
24    24 4.9739
25    25 4.9814
26    26 4.9840
27    27 4.9872
28    28 4.9909
29    29 4.9918
30    30 4.9934
31    31 4.9950
32    32 4.9968
33    33 4.9969
34    34 4.9977
35    35 4.9988
36    36 4.9990
37    37 4.9997
38    38 5.0000

Y ~ gam(y ~ s(x, k = 20)) # thin-plate smooth
```

I tried altering the basis dimension (k) as well (my strategy is to double k and refit; clearly, k cannot be greater than the number of observations), but I am finding that no value of k seems to do a good job in terms of gam.check().

Any ideas here on how to get decent results (could be due to small sample size too)?

Comment: It looks like you have only one independent variable, guessing from the dimensionality of the $(1,1)$.  If you really need the fit to pass through that, just subtract $1$ from both $y$ and $x$, so when the splines pass through $(0,0)$ with the transformed values they will be passing through $(1,1)$ with the untransformed values.

Comment: Thanks! Just so that I am clear, you are suggesting something like (y - 1) ~ s((x - 1)) in specifying the GAM model in mgcv ? And yes, I have only one idependent variable as well as a single covariate.

Comment: Yes... would that do the job for you?

Comment: It doesn't seem that way. I have added my data to my question post

Comment: There doesn't appear to be much randomness in the plot of the data - are you actually trying to interpolate rather than fit a function that assumes randomness in the data?

Comment: I realize that my data does not contain much noise. I was thinking of adding some random jitter so that the data can be smoothed rather than interpolated. But the reason for using GAMs is to be able to compare different basis functions via AIC and use prediction to obtain CIs for $x$. I am using inverse regression to find x given a realization of the response $y$

Comment: Any further ideas here?

Comment: I don't really follow this; with the data & `gam` call you showed, the spline doesn't pass through (0,0) and certainly isn't constrained to do so. The spline is subject to a sum-to-zero constraint, which leads the spline being centred about the model constant term. You can force the spline to pass through some value, but as it doesn't pass through (0,0), I think you need to explain why you think this is happening and why you want it to pass through (1,1).

Comment: Thanks Gavin. I've actually decided to go with an adaptive smooth (bs = "ad") since I will be fitting many simulated datasets of varying sizes. My reasoning for this is because on plotting the smooth, I notice there is a rapid increase in the response followed by decelerating slope to an eventual asymptote. Adopting an adaptive smooth fixes the issues with EDF and k' (= k - 1), but the deviance residual plots are not really that great, as they show trends such as heavy-tails in QQplots and/or heteroscedasticity in residual vs. fitted plots.

Comment: As per explaining why I thought that the spline wasn't behaving properly, I suspect that there may be some overfitting occurring, since the data don't show a high degree of variability. But I think this may have been solved through trying out an adaptive smooth with 20 degrees of freedom.